# FFprobe - Cut last 30s with bash script

Tags: bash, macos, ffmpeg, ffprobe

I'm trying to use the **ffprobe** and **bash loop script** to subtract from the length of the video last 10sec. But it writes me a syntax error. Any ideas?

```
for f in *.mp4; do \
videoduration=$(ffprobe -i $f -show_entries format=duration -sexagesimal -v quiet -of csv="p=0"); \
cutduration=00:00:10.000000; \
duration=$((videoduration - cutduration)); \
echo "$duration"; done
```

Comment: bash doesn't do floating point arithmetic, you'll need to delegate a tool such as `bc`.

Comment: Thank u! Solved :)